# how to refresh my record count from database - asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have in my asp.net web-page `label` that contain result of count record query.

i need to see refresh this query and see the correct record count.

how to see it ?  i need any timer ?  how to do it without Flickers ?

can i get any sample C# asp.net code ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Personally I would use jQuery to refresh the count. Since i assume that the count is being changed because of an user action you could also let the count being refreshed after the action, that changes the count is finished

Comment: Code example would also be nice. Makes the question more clear

Comment: How are you populating the label the first time? What event would cause the value to change? (Start by putting the answers of these two questions together.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

**Client**
http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/call-php-ajax-every-second-jquery.html

**Server**

```
YourAjaxMethod()
{
Response.Write("ContentForLabel");
Response.End();
}
```